# DB Seeding Error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'client_id' in 'field list'

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, uuid, laravel-seeding

My top-level table is `clients` and the table `users` belongs to `clients`. This is the error I get when trying to seed the user's table.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not
>   found: 1054 Unknown column 'client_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert
>   into `users` (`client_id`, `name`, `email`, `client_uuid`, `uuid`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (test, test, test@test.com,
>   412f251d-324b-472e-80ab-b06c5c61e732,
>   aaa4eaa0-fa63-11e8-9402-ebda32c76206, 2018-12-07 21:04:20, 2018-12-07
>   21:04:20))

**Clients Schema**

```php
Schema::connection('mysql_migrations')->create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('uuid')->primary();
    $table->string('name', 200);
    $table->string('password', 200);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Users Schema**

```php
Schema::connection('mysql_migrations')->create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('uuid')->primary();
    $table->uuid('client_uuid');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email');
    $table->timestamp('accessed_at')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Clients Seeder**

```php
DB::table('clients')->insert([
    'uuid' => '412f251d-324b-472e-80ab-b06c5c61e732',
    'name' => 'Example client',
    'password' => Hash::make('test'),
]);
```

**Users Seeder**

```php
factory(App\User::class, 5)->create([
    'client_uuid' => '412f251d-324b-472e-80ab-b06c5c61e732',
    'name' => 'test',
    'email' => 'test@test.com',
]);
```

**Client Model**

```php
class Client extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use \BinaryCabin\LaravelUUID\Traits\HasUUID;

    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'client_uuid', 'uuid');
    }

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'client_uuid';
    }

    public function getKeyName()
    {
        return 'uuid';
    }

}
```

**User Model**

```php
class User extends Model
{
    use \BinaryCabin\LaravelUUID\Traits\HasUUID;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'client_uuid',
    ];

    protected $dates = ['accessed_at'];

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class, 'client_uuid', 'uuid');
    }

    public function getKeyName()
    {
        return 'uuid';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's telling you there is no column `users.client_id.` At some point, you must have had an extra column name `users.client_id` alongside `users.client_uuid.` Delete your tables, run the migrations again and then retry the seeder.

Comment: I did rename the column from client_id to client_uuid. But clearing the cache with artisan and rerunning the migration has had no effect. My assumption is that "client_id" is the default field name, and it's being generated somewhere that I'm not overwriting it.

Comment: Turns out there was still a 'client_id' column name in my seeder factory. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I renamed column but still there are traces of old field name anywhere (factory, migration), yet it's using old field name at the seeder step. Seems to be a bug.
Is there any cache involved?
Wierd.